# iphone: Good practice for keeping my third-party libraries up-to-date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to ask about your practices to keep your third-party libraries up-to-date easily.

In my iPhone project, I use quite a lot third-party libs (like TouchXML, JSON, RegexKit, YAJL, MGTwitterEngine...). Most of them is stored in GitHub and their version, especially MGTwitterEngine, change quite rapidly (because of adding new feature, fixing bug, changing in Server(like Twitter) response format...).

Sometimes, I forget to update (also don't want to change the stable version) then my project get bugs because of out-of-date libraries.

When I got a bug because the old libraries. I often go to Github, download the new version, then need to change a lot of code. Because downloading new version means I do a fast-forward from a very old version to the latest version. I think It will less painful if I update the library more frequently.

What is your approach for this task?

Comment: Three votes without any answer. Why? Can u give some comment?

Comment: It's because other people (including me) are also interested in your question, but no one has an answer yet.

Comment: If we don't have the answer, just raise idea and discuss by comment :)

Can we write a script to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked into [git submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html)?

I use them for this task.  We have a repository of helper classes.  However, whenever we make additions & improvements, we want those improvements to be cascaded to all of our projects -- so, we set up that helper repository as a submodule in each project repository.

Try the following command from within your repository's root directory:

```
git submodule add ssh://url/to/external/library.git local/path
```

This should do the following steps (taken verbatim from the URL above):

> - Clones the submodule under the current directory and by default checks out the master branch.
> - Adds the submodule's clone path to the `.gitmodules` file and adds
>     this file to the index, ready to be committed.
> - Adds the submodule's current commit ID to the index, ready to be committed.

You can then use the

```
git submodule update
```

command to keep things up-to-date.

Also, as a side note, if you are doing what I am (e.g. making direct changes to the submodule repository), you need to go to the submodule's root repository directory and commit those changes FIRST before committing the super-project.  This is because git keeps track of the versions of the submodules (smart), so if you commit the superproject first, you'll be storing a reference to changes that haven't been committed on the submodule repository.  Anyone who tries to clone your superproject will get an error.

Comment: I will try this approach. Thank you very much, phooze.

Comment: +1 git submodules definitely is the way to go. We use this approach a lot.

Answer (score 5):

It is now 2012, and since this question was asked two projects have emerged which aim to make it much easier to manage project dependencies in iOS code: [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods) and [VendorKit](http://vendorkit.com/). Both are inspired by the Ruby dependency manager [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/). CocoaPods is probably the most mature and active project, but both are gaining traction.

Git submodules help **a lot** in organizing your project and dependencies, but it can still be a hassle to get the search paths and linker flags right, not to mention figuring out what's wrong if the dependencies break. It's also hard to deal with the situation where A and B both depend on C, where A is your own project and B and C are dependencies. So my advice, at this point in time, would be to use one of these projects and support them by writing specs for various libraries.

There is also the lesser-known [Kit](https://github.com/nkpart/kit), implemented in Haskell. Worth checking out.

Comment: For making sure all settings are properly setup (search-paths, ...), we use custom frameworks as suggested by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343242/objective-c-how-to-make-a-framework/8343513#8343513).