# iOS static framework and static library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, static-libraries

This [link](http://blog.bugsense.com/post/12330021520/creating-a-framework-for-ios) discusses how to create iOS static framework, and they said

> With static libraries, everything else (including 
>   the header files) you must distribute separately.

Actually I found no difference between using static lib and framework, you can look at the Admob SDK (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/), what they ask is just pull all the files in the XCode project, so I really don't understand why we need to use framework over just plain static lib, or am I missing something?

Comment: You should need the `.a` file plus the `.h` files, and also any sound or image files, etc.

Comment: a Framework usually combines the header files and .m files in one package, unlike a library which only has the source (.m) files, and you have to add the header files separately to your project.

Comment: You were not allowed to include a Framework in Xcode 3 - just libraries. At some Xcode 4 started to support them.

Comment: @DavidH that is wrong. Custom frameworks using dynamic libraries were always prohibited on iOS (non jailbroken). Custom frameworks using static libraries were always supported (by supported, I mean using them worked fine already on Xcode 3).

Comment: @Howard we do not "need" to use them, it is mostly a convenience thing. It is just much more convenient to add a framework compared to adding a library and a bunch of headers.

Comment: Have a look at this thread for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343242/objective-c-how-to-make-a-framework

Comment: @Till, I remember going to a site that had all kinds of convoluted tricks to make it possible to create a framework with a static library. You even had to make an OSX version first, then modify it. Now, I see them all the time. Included project support is vastly easier in 4 than in 3. I guess in the end YMMV but my experience in 3 was not good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically a framework is a collection of static libraries (e.g. one for i386, one for ARM) and the header files. Furthermore a framework also is a special folder with a very well defined structure.

I am not quit sure what you mean by 'just add the folder in Xcode'...
If you mean adding a folder containing all the source code or a folder containing the static library including the header files you are right and there (very often) is no really big difference (depending on the library to include).

Using a framework is primarily a usability thing. Adding a framework, which means adding one single artifact, is less error prone than adding a bunch of files. For example it is not possible to accidentally omit one header file.